# How to deploy nodejs and vuejs to heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, deployment

How can I can deploy my project to heroku.
My code base here:
[image: img]

I try to deploy to heroku but I always get an error.

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz

 !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
 !     
 !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
 !         
 !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
 !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
 !     following files:
 !     
 !     Procfile
 !     server/
 !     tsconfig.json
 !     vue/
 !         
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
 !         
 !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

Can I change a heroku config to uses package file in sub folder?

Comment: package.json file need to be on root file then heroku can understand this is nodejs project

Comment: try to follow this link https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489 and change the app structure

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehmanKhan So, should I change my project structure. Right?

Comment: yes change the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please restructure your app, Heroku identity app by its app structure.

In your `root` directory there is not `package.json` file

Its best if you deploy `back-end` and `front-end` as separate apps

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding.